# ssrs export to excel tab names on empty tablix

Tags: reporting-services, render

I have a report with multiple tablixes each nestled in separate rectangles  I have the page break set and page name assigned in each tablix.   The problem appears that if a tablix has no data the excel tab shows the table header but the tab name appears to hold from the prior tab name.  For example I get Summary ta, labor tab equipment tab and equipment(2) tab because the table following equipment is empty.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your issue. I've tried putting the page breaks and page names on individual tables as well as on the rectangles with tables in them. With no data in the second table, the second sheet still gets the second name. Some things to try: 1. Add the page name to the table properties in addition to the rectangle. 2. Add a "no rows message" to the table with a space in it so it has some content.

Answer (score 0):

So the report is pretty much a data dump with multiple tablixes that represent different data, for for example safety, quality, etc.  The tablixes are inside separate rectangles.
I created separate datasets for each tablix that gets the table name.  The table name is a translation for the language that name is to render, English, Spanish, etc.
I created a parameter for each table tab name that now holds the name for the table tab.
I set each tablix pagename to the corresponding parameter.
Now when I export to Excel each tab has the appropriate tab name in the appropriate language.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Here's what I did to solve it:
Had a check in sql if count of rows is 0 then 'NA' will be the value for all columns; otherwise original values from table.

In SSRS, I am going to hide the text box if it has a value "NA". 
You can try to hide the entire row in ssrs if the value is "NA". But its not going to work. Hiding the individual text box will work for sure.

Condition to hide: IIF(Fields!columnname="NA",true,false)

After all these steps if you export to excel it will show the group name you have given.